# Defining the functional integral measure from the generating functional

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, path-integral, perturbation-theory

In standard QFT we define the generating functional from the functional integral as $${\cal Z}[j]=\int\mathfrak{D}\phi e^{-S[\phi]+i\int d^Dx j(x)\phi(x)}\tag{1}.$$

On the other hand, intuitively speaking, it seems that ${\cal Z}[j]$ also *defines* the functional integral. Indeed, any polynomial in the fields $\phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)$ can be integrated by differentiating ${\cal Z}[j]$. So if we don't know the measure, but somehow know ${\cal Z}[j]$, then we can *define* $$\int \mathfrak{D}\phi e^{-S[\phi]}\phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n):=(-i)^n \dfrac{\delta^n{\cal Z}}{\delta j(x_1)\cdots \delta j(x_n)}\bigg|_{j=0}\tag{2}$$

which in turn defines the functional integral of polynomials. I think that it also should define the functional integral of any functional which is the limit of a sequence of polynomials.

None of this is rigorous, really, but then looking into the book by Glimm & Jaffe we find the Bochner-Minlos theorem:

> If $d\nu$ is a regular Borel measure on $\scr S'$ with total weight $1$, then its generating functional $S$ satisfies (i)-(iii) above [continuity, positive-definiteness and normalization]. Conversely, given a functional $S$ defined on $\mathscr{S}$ and satisfying (i)-(iii) above, then $S$ is the inverse Fourier transform of a unique regular Borel measure $d\nu$ with normalization $\int d\nu = 1$.

So it seems that the non-rigorous discussion can indeed be made rigorous in some sense.

1. So is it really correct to think of the functional integral being *defined* by ${\cal Z}[j]$? In that sense, the Dyson-Schwinger functional-differential equation for ${\cal Z}[j]$ would really be an equation to determine the functional integral measure?
2. In that setting would it be more accurate to view the generating functional ${\cal Z}_0[j]$ associated to the quadratic action $S_0$ as being *defined* by $${\cal Z}_0[j] = \exp\left(-\frac{i}{2}\int dxdy j(x)D(x-y)j(y)\right),$$ where $D(x-y)$ is the Feynman propagator? In that point of view we would take this as a definition motivated by finite-dimensional Gaussian integrals and invoking this Bochner-Minlos theorem it would be the definition of the integral against the measure $\mathfrak{D}\phi e^{-S_0[\phi]}$

Comment: Regarding 2: I'd say that you can of course define the generating functional in any way you want, but the non-trivial value seems to be in being able to say that there exists a measure that gives rise to this functional. To be clear, there are (in Glimm&Jaffe) constructions of measures which are not through the generating functional. (IIRC)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but maybe it adds to the motivation for the question: In much of the more mathematically-oriented literature about anomalies associated with chiral fermions in background gauge/gravitational fields, the functional integral is typically *defined* by a regulated version of the determinant that the integral is supposed to yield.

Comment: I suspect something like this should be true, given that in probability theory, the moment generating function (if it exists) uniquely determines the probability distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Important_properties

Comment: @Andrew: the correspondence measure/moments is quite tricky, look up Hamburger moment problem. However, the correspondence measure/characteristic function is perfect and that is the content of Bochner's Theorem.

Comment: @Gold: The correspondence between the functional integral and the characteristic function $Z(j)$ is perfect provided you are talking about Euclidean functional integrals. So one should avoid $Z_0$ with an $i$. Also, there is no need for the word "regular" in the Bochner-Minlos Theorem because $S'$ is a Radon space. GJ's formulation of the theorem is thus a bit redundant.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Indeed, in true physicist fashion I am just assuming anything relevant for physics will converge :) But if the moment generating function doesn't exist / there are convergence issues, things will get a lot more complicated, and it also wouldn't surprise me if these issues were very relevant in QFT.

Comment: @Andrew: In QFT one expects the moments to grow like a power of $n!$ which is at most 1. This is enough to rule out the kind of pathologies I mentioned about the moment problem.